# Copy contents recursively with existing symbolic links to directories on target

Tags: rsync, symlink, cp

```
mkdir -p source/{dir1,dir2}
touch source/a
touch source/dir1/b
touch source/dir2/c

mkdir -p target/dir1
mkdir dir_link
ln -s ../dir_link target/dir2
```

So at start we have:

```
tree

├── dir_link
├── source
│   ├── a
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── b
│   └── dir2
│       └── c
└── target
    ├── dir1
    └── dir2 -> ../dir_link
```

Using:

```
cp -r source/* target
```

the result is:

> cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'target/dir2' with directory 'source/dir2'

```
├── dir_link
├── source
│   ├── a
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── b
│   └── dir2
│       └── c
└── target
    ├── a
    ├── dir1
    │   └── b
    └── dir2 -> ../dir_link
```

I'm looking for a command (cp, rsync) that can understand that source/dir2/c should be copied to target/dir2 (which is a dir symbolic link)

The closest will be the `-H` option for cp

> -H     follow command-line symbolic links in SOURCE

but applied to TARGET

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -avhK source/* target
```

follow dir symbolic link correctly:

```
├── dir_link
│   └── c
├── source
│   ├── a
│   ├── dir1
│   │   └── b
│   └── dir2
│       └── c
└── target
    ├── a
    ├── dir1
    │   └── b
    └── dir2 -> ../dir_link
```

More info in https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync `-K --copy-dirlinks`